# Comparison Theorem: compare solutions to ODE with different parameters.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a one dimension ODE that takes the following form

$au'(x) + bx u(x)+cx-\gamma=0$ with $u(0)=\eta$, where $a,c>0$, $b<0$.

Now I want to see $u(x)$ as parameterized by $\gamma$ and consider two different ODEs with $\gamma_1<\gamma_2$, i.e.,

$au_1'(x) + bx u_1(x)+cx-\gamma_1=0$, $u_1(0)=\eta$,

$au_2'(x) + bx u_2(x)+cx-\gamma_2=0$, $u_2(0)=\eta$.

The question is to prove $u_1(x)<u_2(x)$ for all $x>0$.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: That's almost certainly in Coddington and Levinson: https://smile.amazon.com/Theory-Ordinary-Differential-Equations-Coddington-dp-0898747554/dp/0898747554/ref=mt_hardcover?_encoding=UTF8&me=&qid=1559678841

Comment: What equation does $u_1-u_2$ satisfy? (This is a hint.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\delta =u_1-u_2$ and note that $\delta$ satisfies
$\delta' +{b\over a} x\delta = {1 \over a}(\gamma_1-\gamma_2)$, with $\delta(0) = 0$.

Using the usual integrating factor, we have
${d \over dx}(e^{b x^2 \over 2a} \delta) = {1 \over a}(\gamma_1-\gamma_2) < 0$ from
which we can easily check that $\delta(x)<0$ for $x >0$.